# Will android 5.0.1 sdk package work for android 5.0.4?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, android, appium

I have Android 5.0.4, so which **Android SDK** package do I need to Install?

[image: Android SDK]

There are two Options available in Android SDK Manager

- ANDROID 5.1.1
- ANDROID 5.0.1

My Device : 5.0.4

Answer (score 3):

I think you have asked wrong information.
While automating Mobile browsers/applications we will use appium & this will work for ***ANDROID with above API-17 level***. It means you must have Android device of version above-4.2.2. Confirm your Android device version- `Go to Setting--> about Phone-->Android version.`  According to the version of your Android install/download by selecting API level. If your Android version in between them i.e version-5.0.4 then you may select as API 22.

> Select greater version every time it will works.